# iPhone prompt to update

Tags: iphone, padrino

I am currently working on an API for an iPhone app, which is for the version 2 of the app.
(APIs were developed in Padrino)

So I still have the old API for version 1 iPhone app.

What I wanted to do is to prompt the iPhone app user (if possible) to download the latest version of the app and iPhone user will not be able to access the iPhone app version 1 anymore.

any inputs will be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, at least for AppStore apps. But: almost every user updates his app if an update is available (they're notified by AppStore on the device or through iTunes), and after they had upgraded the app, they won't have access to the old version (unless they have specifically saved an older version of the .ipa file, which is also unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

The prompt would have to be something that you programmed into v1 of the app. You could 'trigger' the method at app startup or something.

Turning off the old web services for v1, while possible, and 'disabling'/breaking the v1 app would be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *impossible*, rather shouldn't be a standard practice. The easiest thing for you to do is check against a web service or possibly even a remote file that contains the latest version info, then show a message to the user that there is a newer version available.

I would suggest using maybe a push notification service and when you have an update, send out a message to users *(well, the users who decide to accept push notifications from your app anyway)*.

Also, **not allowing access to version 1** is not something you should do either. In this case, you could prompt the user that they should update to the latest version rather than restricting access to the app.